# How can I silence RuntimeWarning on iteration speed when using Jupyter notebook with Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, warnings, jupyter-notebook

The new version of [wallstreet](https://github.com/mcdallas/wallstreet) package seems to create warning below on each option method. That said, using it on Jupyter Notebook I see no performance or logical calculation errors.

How can I silence errors below for this env, as its making notebook hard to read.

```
p = Put('KORS', d=2, m=6, y=2017, strike=34, source='yahoo')
```

//anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py:161: RuntimeWarning: The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the 
  improvement from the last ten iterations.
  warnings.warn(msg, RuntimeWarning)

```
p.delta()
```

//anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py:161: RuntimeWarning: The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the 
  improvement from the last ten iterations.
  warnings.warn(msg, RuntimeWarning)